# set properties of facebook application using API

Tags: facebook, tabs

I have an app which i only give name of the app. So i have app_id, secret_app_id

I want to add page_tab_url to Page Tab of the app using API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for more detail:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Shortest path to do this:

make a HTTP POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&page_tab_url=http://YOUR PAGE TAB URL`

Comment: I got app_access_token from graph.facebook.com/me/accounts but it shows
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}

How can I get app_access_token?

Comment: Well, /me/accounts will give you a page access token, not an app access token (there may be apps listed there because apps had profile pages until Feb 2012 and the API endpoints haven't yet been cleaned up for them) - an app access token can be [obtained thusly](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin) - Also note that if your app is configured as 'Desktop/Native' you can't use the app access token as its assumed that you've distributed it with the app and it can't be trusted

Comment: It is a very big relieve from this helpful response! now it done.
Thanks Igy,